# How do I check the fluid level in the rear end (differential) on a 1996 Caprice?

Tags: chevrolet, rear-differential, b-body

What is the procedure to check the fluid level in the rear differential?  The RPO code for this particular rear end is G80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the side of the differential housing you will find a plug fitting.The fitting looks similar to an allenhead bolt but it has a four sided hole that a 1/2 ratchet extension will fit into.Remove the plug insert your finger straight in the hole.If it has oil in it the level is ok.If you can't feel any oil you need to fill it to the level of the hole.